# How to bottom align a title of variable length

Tags: html, css

I have a design where I need to align a header to some content in another column.

The header can be of variable length so I am trying to work out how to align the border-bottom in all cases.

(The below is just some demo code to highlight my issue)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header-container">
        <h1>Short title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header-container">
        <h1>This is a much longer title title</h1>
    </div>
</div>​

.header-container 
{
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1.4em;  
    margin: 10px 20px; 
    float: right; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;        
}​
```

Please see

http://jsfiddle.net/bmxSY/

So in the case of the short title the first line should be blank. Is there anyway of doing this with pure css. I might do a count on the characters and add a margin-top but this isnt 100% fool proof.

***EDIT****
The real issue here was that the header needed to align with content in a different containing div. So the Example HTML Markup and CSS should really have been more like...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="header-container">
            <h1>Short title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="header-container">
            <h1>This is a much longer title title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​

.header-container {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1.4em;  
    margin: 10px 20px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
    text-align: left;
}

.span4 
{
    width:60%;
    float: left;
}

.span8
{
    width:40%;
    float: left;
}
```

​

Comment: I don't really understand what you want.. Are you saying you want `.header-container` to stretch the width of the page no matter what the width the content is?

Comment: Please explain what is wrong in the fiddle you posted, what do you want to change in it? it's no clear to me..

Comment: @Everyone he wants "Short Title" to be down, so the border is on line with the other `h1` border. And not manually doing `margin-top:XXpx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Actually it is not possible, but by tricking, we can do it.

```
.outer {
    position:relative;
    display:table;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background:red;
    float:left
}
.inner {
    width:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    position:relative;
}
p{background:blue;border:1px solid #000}
```

#### Demo: http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/vertical-align9.htm

Comment: The problem with this (and probably any other CSS-only) solution is that you have to give the container a fixed height. So if you have a row where all titles are only one line, you will have extra white-space on top of them.

Comment: @teevee giving `height` is not mandatory. You can remove the height!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is with `display: inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/bmxSY/7/

```css
.container {
    text-align: right;
}
.header-container {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1.4em;  
    margin: 10px 20px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}​
```

Comment: Well basically my example was pretty poor as I only have one header and the above only works when there is already a div taking up the double line height, which I do have but it is in a separate container. Your way is a lot cleaner but unfortunately I think I need a dirty hack to fix my issue and Praveen Kumar provided that

Comment: That's fine. I just wanted to make sure I hadn't made a silly mistake myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `table-cell` to align the div o the bottom of the parent.

unfortunately `dispaly:table-cell` doesn't support `margin` option so you need to manipulate it through border.

**CSS**

```
.container{display:table-row; float:right}
.header-container
{
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1.4em;  
    border-right:20px solid white;   border-left:20px solid white;
    border-top:10px solid white;   border-bottom:10px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;        
    display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bmxSY/5/)**